# Efficiently find which datacenter my machine is in along with its full node?

Tags: java, enums, hostname

In our company we can have a machine hostname as  -

```
dbx111.dc1.host.com
dbx112.dc2.host.com
dcx113.dc3.host.com
```

Here `dc1`, `dc2`, `dc3` are our datacenter and we will be having only three datacenter for now. And also it might be possible that machine hostname can have more dots in between separated by another domain in future.

Now I need to find out which `datacenter` my current machine is in as I will be running below code on the actual machine. If my machine is in `DC1` then I need to return `/zk/dc1` but if my machine is in `DC2` then I need to return `/zk/dc2` and if my machine is in `DC3` then I would return `/zk/dc3`.

But if my machine datacenter is in `DEV`, then I would randomly return either `/zk/dc1` or `/zk/dc2`.

Currently my below code only writtens, in which DATACENTER I am in such as whether it is either `DC1 or DC2 or DC3 or DEV`. But I am not sure how to add the above logic as well in this ENUM so that it can also return me `/zk/dc1` or `/zk/dc2` or `/zk/dc3` depending on which datacenter I am in.

And also if I just need to get only which Datacenter I am in, then it should be able to work that way as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(DatacenterEnum.getCurrentDatacenter());
}

public enum DatacenterEnum {

    DEV, DC1, DC2, DC3;

    public static String forCode(int code) {
    return (code >= 0 && code < values().length) ? values()[code].name() : null;
    }

    private static final DatacenterEnum ourlocation = compareLocation();

    private static DatacenterEnum compareLocation() {
    String ourhost = getHostName();
    for (DatacenterEnum dc : values()) {
        String namepart = "." + dc.name().toLowerCase() + ".";
        if (ourhost.indexOf(namepart) >= 0) {
        return dc;
        }
    }
    return null;
    }

    private static final String getHostName() {
    try {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName().toLowerCase();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {      
        //log error
    }
    return null;
    }

    public static DatacenterEnum getCurrentDatacenter() {
    return ourlocation;
    }       
}
```

Any idea how this can be done efficiently?

Comment: I Like that you want something including a DNS lookup to be efficient!

Comment: Also consider if you will silently accept your program breaking if your network administrator change DNS or move your program.  Put configuration outside your code.  Property files are cheap to read.

Comment: this is just a bad idea -- the whole naming thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void toZkString() {
    if (this == DEV) {
        return new Random().nextBoolean() ? "/zk/dc1" : "/zk/dc2";
    }
    return "/zk/" + name().toLowercase();
}

private static final String OUR_LOCATION_AS_ZK_STRING = ourlocation.toZkString();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. In this case what is name here? Sorry got confused currently?

Comment: name() is the name of the enum, i.e. "DC1", "DC2", "DC3" or "DEV". Every enum has one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29

Comment: Yeah but this name will be the name of the current datacenter in which I am in correct?

Comment: Have you at least tried to understand the 6 lines of code I posted? The method is called on ourlocation, right? And ourlocation is our location, right?

Comment: @JaceRhea: agreed. But I don't see anything that needs explanation, to someone who's already using enums, already using toLowercase(), should know what ourlocation is since he has defined it, and should understand what Random.nextBoolean() does without any explanation.

Comment: @JBNizet I came across this answer as it was flagged for low quality due to the length. Something to consider in the future.